# MongoDB Aggregation branch calculation based on some condition?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, conditional-statements, calculation

I have a range of values:

```
[{
    "Reserviert": {
        "Zeitstempel": "2018-06-06T18:19:42.317Z",
        "Wert": 46
    }
}, {
    "Reserviert": {
        "Zeitstempel": "2018-06-06T18:34:42.317Z",
        "Wert": 48
    }
}, {
    "Reserviert": {
        "Zeitstempel": "2018-07-09T14:52:32.472Z",
        "Wert": 104
    }
}, {
    "Reserviert": {
        "Zeitstempel": "2018-07-09T15:07:32.472Z",
        "Wert": 102
    }
}, {
    "Reserviert": {
        "Zeitstempel": "2018-07-09T14:52:32.472Z",
        "Wert": 20
    }
}, {
    "Reserviert": {
        "Zeitstempel": "2018-07-09T15:07:32.472Z",
        "Wert": 24
    }
}, {
    "Reserviert": {
        "Zeitstempel": "2018-07-09T14:52:32.472Z",
        "Wert": 94
    }
}, {
    "Reserviert": {
        "Zeitstempel": "2018-07-09T15:07:32.472Z",
        "Wert": 90
    }
}, {
    "Reserviert": {
        "Zeitstempel": "2018-07-09T14:52:32.473Z",
        "Wert": 33
    }
}, {
    "Reserviert": {
        "Zeitstempel": "2018-07-09T15:07:32.473Z",
        "Wert": 29
    }
}, {
    "Reserviert": {
        "Zeitstempel": "2018-07-09T14:52:32.473Z",
        "Wert": 15
    }
}]
```

now, I would like to do a calculation: Once sum all "Wert" values for all documents that exist. And the other time, I want to pass a Date-range, and then calculate only the sum of values based on that date range. How can I do this?
Is there something like "branching" in mongoDB aggregation?
Because if I calculate the one thing, I cannot calculate the other branch, because the pipeline already changed my input from previous pipelines for that...

I already did the basic date-range calculation, etc. but no Idea how to go to a previous "state" of my calculation, and then do a calculation based on some date-range condition (after I have calculated e.g the sum for the whole date-range)

**e.g I could do calculation for date-range... and then sum up all products that are in date range.. but then I cannot go back again and calculate the total sum of products (also from those that are outside the date range) e.g. if I wanted to calculate the ratio between them..**

```
                $project: {
                    ProdukteImZeitraum: 
                      {
                          cond: { $and: [
                            { $gte: ["Reserviert.Zeitstempel", new Date(req.params.start) ] },
                            { $lte: ["Reserviert.Zeitstempel", new Date(req.params.end) ] }
                          ] 
                        }
                      }
                }
            }/*,
            {
                $group: {
                    _id: null,
                    res: {$addToSet: "$Reserviert.Wert"}                
                }


            },
            {
                $addFields: {
                    AlleProdukteSumme: {
                    $sum: "$res"        
                    }
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `$facet` pipeline stage to branch your pipeline into two different calculations (https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/facet/):

```
[
  $facet: {
    totalSum: [
      { $group: { _id: null, totalSum: {$sum: '$Reserviert.Wert'}} }
    ],
    dateRangeSum: [
      { $match: { 'Reserviert.Zeitstempel': {
          $gte: new Date(req.params.start), 
          $lte: new Date(req.params.end)} 
      } },
      { $group: { _id: null, totalSum: {$sum: '$Reserviert.Wert'}} }
    ]
  }
]
```